# Can the product of an exponential and a hypergeometric function be expressed as a Meijer-G function?

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

Let $0<\alpha< 1$. Can the function

$\qquad e^{-\alpha x}U(a,b,x),$

where $U(a,b,z)$ is the [hypergeometric U function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) be expressed as a Meijer-G function?

The closest I found was [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricU/26/02/02/) which corresponds to $\alpha=1$.

Comment: This seems more a math problem than a Mathematica problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for this?

```
MeijerGReduce[E^(-z α) HypergeometricU[a, b, z], z]
```

$$\frac{\text{MeijerG}\left(\{\{\},\{\}\},\left\{\left\{0,\frac{1}{2}\right\},\{\}\right\},\frac{\alpha  z}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right) \text{MeijerG}(\{\{1-a\},\{\}\},\{\{0,1-b\},\{\}\},z)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (a) \Gamma (a-b+1)}$$

I have constrained $0< \alpha< 1$, and I also got the same result.

Comment: I was looking to see if it can be written as a single Meijer-G function. I have an integral of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{it/x}e^{-\alpha x} U(a,b,x)\mathrm{d}x$.  I am looking to hopefully write the integrand as the product of two Meijer-G functions to help solve it.

Comment: Thought the Mellin transform approach could be used as in this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153852/express-as-meijer-g-function?rq=1

Comment: Mellin Transform gives a sum of two `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized` functions. You could try to express them as `Meijer`functions, and see what your integral does.

Comment: I suggest you move your question to mathematics.stackexchange.com. Once you have a clear path to do it, come back for doing it with MMA if you have issues or help